# How do I change the timeout on a jasmine-node async spec

Tags: node.js, jasmine

How can I get this test to pass without resorting to runs/waitsFor blocks?

```
it("cannot change timeout", function(done) {

     request("http://localhost:3000/hello", function(error, response, body){

         expect(body).toEqual("hello world");

         done();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Sent pull request for this feature (https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/pull/142)

```
it("cannot change timeout", function(done) {

  request("http://localhost:3000/hello", function(error, response, body){

     expect(body).toEqual("hello world");

     done();
  });

}, 5000); // set timeout to 5 seconds
```

Comment: don't think the PR got merged.

Answer (score 132):

You can (now) set it directly in the spec, as per [Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-47).

```
describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {

    var originalTimeout;

    beforeEach(function() {
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    });

    it("takes a long time", function(done) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            done();
        }, 9000);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, changing ```jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;``` value did the trick for me on a brand new setup built from scratch using Jasmine + Jest. It works as expected.

Comment: I agree @willydee, had issues runnig tests with cloudinary and this little snippet came to my rescue.

Comment: Worth noting perhaps that this has to happen before the `it`. By the time you're in the test, `done` seems to have already hooked into whatever `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` was before `it` started.

Answer (score 44):

To set the global Jasmine-Node timeout, do this:

```
jasmine.getEnv().defaultTimeoutInterval = timeoutYouWouldPrefer;// e.g. 15000 milliseconds
```

Credit to developer Gabe Hicks for figuring out the .getEnv() part via debugging in spite of misinformation in the [README doc](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/master/README.md) which claims it's done by setting jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

If you want to set a custom timeout just for one it(), you could try passing the timeout (milliseconds) as a third argument (after the string statement and the function). There's an example of that being done [here](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/master/spec/async-callback_spec.js), but I'm not sure what would happen if the custom timeout was longer than Jasmine's default. I expect it would fail.

Comment: Update for anyone stumbling on this answer in 2014: For Jasmine 2 setting jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL works.

Comment: It works for me on a brand new setup using Jest + Jasmine. I just added ```jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 12000;``` on a global config file I use for all tests and it works as expected.

Answer (score 30):

Looks like you can now add it as the last argument for the `it` function:

```
describe('my test', function(){
    it('works', function(done){
        somethingAsync().then(done);
    }, 10000); // changes to 10 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 13):

In Angular, put this outside your describe block:

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
```

This applies to all the tests in the .spec.ts file

Answer (score 4):

Put it after `describe` statement:

```js
describe("A saves to DB", function() {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding: `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = yourTime;` on a helper file worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had multiple tests cases and while I was using the aforementioned solution with was using the:

```
    beforeEach(function() {
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    });
```

the DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL was not updated at the first test case, so I had to add this:

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
  })
```

to my code to successfully run all the tests.

Answer (score 1):

To do this globally for all of your tests (in the case of e2e or integration testing) you can use a helper.

A helper file when configured correctly should get loaded before the tests are executed and allow you to change the DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL globally:

spec/support/jasmine.json

```json
{
    ...
    "helpers": [
        "/path/to/helpers/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

helpers/timeout.ts

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 300000;
```

Comment: They asked for nodejs, not typescript.

Comment: @MatejVoboril The same applies to js, just change the file extension to .js...

Answer (score 0):

Why not by spying on `setTimeout()`?

Something like:

```
var spy = spyOn(window, 'setTimeout').andCallFake(function (func, timeout) {
    expect(timeout).toEqual(2500);
    func();
});

setTimeOut(function () { ... }, 2500);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks. These are integration tests, node.js is calling out to an external service that is often slow.

Comment: this is brilliant, it makes it possible to test the timeout without making the test wait for the actual timeout

Comment: in this fashion we don't exercise the passage of time, and calling the fn right away, while the original never calls it before the next cycle.

Answer (score -21):

Change j$.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL to 10000 in following file: npm\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core

Comment: Not fruitful for the scenarios where libraries are installed every time test is run. Ex:- running CI on Cloud.