# How to override protractor's default timeout?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

How can I override default timeout(`defaultTimeoutInterval`) for `it` and `describe` methods in Protractor? It's defaulted to `2500ms`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just found the answer myself.

In `config.js`:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 25000
},
```

Comment: Hi, I need to override the default preference that you put in config, only for 1 "it"... I try passing a 3th parmeter to the "it" but didnt work.

Comment: @facundo-pedrazzini as a workaround I would put this "it" into a separate describe and applied the solution described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34291826/292787

Comment: @facundo-pedrazzini I have added an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54045328/558509

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default timeout in a specific `it` test using these two functions to override then restore the default: (Only tested in Chrome)

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

export function DefaultTimeoutOverride(milliseconds: number) {
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(milliseconds);
}

export function DefaultTimeoutRestore() {
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(browser.allScriptsTimeout);
}
```

**EDIT**

I have now created a helper function ('itTO') that wraps Jasmine's 'it' statement and applies the timeout automatically :)

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

export function itTO(expectation: string, assertion: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout: number): void {
    it(expectation, AssertionWithTimeout(assertion, timeout), timeout);
}

function AssertionWithTimeout<T extends Function>(fn: T, timeout: number): T {
    return <any>function(...args) {
        DefaultTimeoutOverride(timeout);
        const response = fn(...args);
        DefaultTimeoutRestore();
        return response;
    };
}

function DefaultTimeoutOverride(milliseconds: number) {
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(milliseconds);
}

function DefaultTimeoutRestore() {
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(browser.allScriptsTimeout);
}
```

use like this:

```
itTO('should run longer than protractors default', async () => {
        await delay(14000);
}, 15000);

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a hack, but the only way I could get it to work was by putting this code in one of my steps.js files:

```
const { setDefaultTimeout } = require('cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(28 * 1000);
```

I tried `jasmineNodeOpts` and `cucumberOpts`, in my `conf.js`, but they didn't work for me.

Screenshot of what I did:

[image]