# How to run protractor suites one after another?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have two files "test.js" and "gmail.js"(Mail listener 2). I need to run "test.js" file first and then after 2 minutes i need to run "gmail.js" file.

Is it possible?

Comment: I would add a `browser.sleep(120000);` in `beforeAll` for the second file. Adding to it using the protractor config file to order the files execution order, it should give you the result you are expecting. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AnnaN Can you share the code please...I don't know how to put it.

Comment: @raghavendrat done, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to properly configure your `specs` parameter in the Protractor config:

```
specs: [
    "path/to/test.js",
    "path/to/gmail.js",
],
```

`specs` are executed *sequentially* one by one.

As far as adding a time delay, you can put it under the `beforeAll` into `gmail.js`:

```
describe("Should test something", function () {
    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.sleep(120000);  // wait for 2 minutes
    });

    it("should do something", function () {
        // your test logic here
    });
}, 300000);  // adjusting the default timeout interval -- 5 minutes for this spec
```

Comment: I tried the above answer but as soon as i run the script it is running the second file also.(gmail.js file contains mail listener 2 test case).

Comment: @raghavendrat have you added the desired time delay into the second spec?

Comment: No i didn't... How to add the time delay?Can u send me the code please

Comment: @raghavendrat `browser.sleep(120000)` to wait for 2 minutes. Note that you would also need to adjust the spec's default jasmine timeout interval: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9957990/771848. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.. i will try and let you know.

Comment: I tried and its not executing second file (gmail.js) now, but now it's waiting 2 minutes. Can u share with me your personnel mail id so that i will share all my user credentials.Please help me.